# TO get full path of a file using ant

Tags: ant

this is the ant script which i have written

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Hello World Project" basedir="." default="info">
<property name="cms.dir" value="D:\CMS\webclient\components\CMS" />
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
<target name="info">
<echo>Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!</echo>
<fileset id="src.files" dir="${cms.dir}" casesensitive="yes">
<include name="**/*.uim"/>
<include name="**/*.properties"/>
</fileset>
<pathconvert pathsep="," property="sounds" refid="src.files">
</pathconvert>
<echo file="sounds.txt">${sounds}</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

its only populating the file name .How can i get the full path of a file

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your fileset in a path element like that :

```
<path id="foo">
 <fileset dir="${cms.dir}" casesensitive="yes">
  <include name="**/*.uim"/>
  <include name="**/*.properties"/>
 </fileset>
</path>
<!-- will print the absolute path of all files separated by ; -->
<echo>${toString:foo}</echo>
```

Use pathconvert with `pathsep="${line.separator"` to get one file per line :

```
<pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="sounds" refid="foo">
```

Also instead of fileset with 2 nested include name elements, you may combine those patterns in fileset includes attribute separated by ',' or blank :

```
<path id="foo">
 <fileset dir="${cms.dir}" casesensitive="yes" includes="**/*.uim **/*.properties"/>
</path>
```